# Rename wordpress.stackexchange to wordpresscore.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

"Wordpress" is too broad of a term when it comes to asking for help. Wordpress themselves segregate their coding standards based on VIP, CORE etc.

This exchange should reflect this. I suggest we push to change the url to core to stop constant nagging of 'third party plugin' answers that close down the question without help.

Comment: I honestly can't see users, who post the questions that you are trying to block, taking a blind bit of notice of a subtle change like that.

Comment: Not warrant of a downvote though, surely there's no negativity when discussing things @Chenmunka

Comment: In Meta StackExchanges votes are related to agreements. Try not to see downvotes as "negative" but more that X users do not think this is a proper change.

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree

Answer (score 8):

This would break thousands of links across hundreds of websites. It's also highly innaccurate.

For example, here are a few things that are on topic, but are not WP Core:

- WP CLI
- The PHPCS coding standards
- The Gutenberg plugin
- The 2FA feature plugin
- The sitemaps effort
- The default themes
- Adding filters to a plugin you're building
- Creating custom rewrite rules
- And many more

None of those are WP Core, but they **are** on topic

> Wordpress themselves segregate their coding standards based on VIP, CORE etc.

The WP Coding standards for PHPCS were actually an independent project until they were officially endorsed. The VIP section is from the WordPress VIP enterprise hosting service ( a 3rd party ), and was added originally by XWP prior to it being officially endorsed.

As the WP VIP employee who created the pull requests to deprecate and remove that coding standard, I can tell you categorically with 100% certainty that your statement is untrue. WPCS didn't want to keep that ruleset, VIP didn't want it in there, and they actually have their own PHPCS ruleset in a separate repository. The ruleset was deprecated in v1.0, and removed in v2.0.

> "Wordpress" is too broad of a term when it comes to asking for help.

The stack is called *WordPress Development*, but keep in mind many people have different ideas of what that encompasses.

For example, some people think that CSS questions about how to style a jQuery carousel plugin are on topic because they did it on a site built with WordPress. If they were asking how to enqueue the script sure that's on topic, but how to modify a CSS rule for a carousel isn't a WP question. Or how to talk

> I suggest we push to change the url to core to stop constant nagging of 'third party plugin' answers that close down the question without help.

If somebody says this in an actual answer you should downvote it, that's what close  votes and comments are for.

#### Notes on 3rd Party Plugins

Remember, this isn't a discussion/support forum, this is a Q&A site.

If a plugin or theme vendor tells you to come here for support, they're breaking the stack exchange terms and conditions.

Additionally:

- If you have to pay for support for a premium plugin or theme, and don't want to or can't pay, this stack isn't a source of help
- If a 3rd party won't help you, that sucks and I empathise, write a review saying so, but otherwise your best bet are the communities of people who use that plugin/theme
- If it's a plugin on the .org site, go to their support forum, **manning the support forums is the price they pay for being hosted on .org**. That's by definition where you're supposed to go. If they don't or won't help you, report them, they risk getting their plugin taken down for being a bad actor
- These questions require specialist expertise in those plugins, and little WordPress knowledge
- If you ask a question about a premium plugin, there's no way for someone to even reproduce it without spending cash to buy it
- A lot of the questions about 3rd party plugins that don't get caught, never get answers anyway

There are plenty of good questions to ask about WordPress, the point being that they're about WordPress, not some random plugin. I gather you really want this stack to be a one stop shop for all things remotely WordPress related, but it isn't. Like all other stacks we have a scope to enforce and a process

#### Improvements That Could Be Made

There are a few things that might help:

- **Improving the wording on the how to ask and what's on topic page**, it does say 3rd party plugins are not on topic, but it could be worded better. Help wanted!
- **Better header graphics**, to make it clear this is a technical stack, not a generic support avenue
- **Reworded close votes**, our current 3rd party close vote actually emphasises generic PHP/CSS questions which are meant to go on stack overflow. This stack isn't there to tell you how to write a for loop or call a function, that's stack overflow! It tags abrief mention of 3rd party plugins on the end, but it should be  the other way around. Sadly, we're only able to specify a limited number of reasons, and some are predefined

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that once a site leaves [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) the URL can change.

What we could do is change the site header / site title. While I don't think either change would discourage off-topic questions from being asked it would at least be another thing to point to when letting users know their question is off-topic.

Comment: A few sites have changed their title and URL post-Area51,  e.g. "Moderators" became "Community Building".  But it is rare.